Какие модификаторы и где нужно применить, чтобы все элементы помещались в альбомной ориентации?
import ...

data class ArtInfo(
    val artId: Int,
    val drawableRes: Int,
    val title: String,
    val author: String,
    val year: Int,
)

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            ComposeTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .statusBarsPadding()
                        .navigationBarsPadding()
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary
                ) {
                    ArtSpaceApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ArtSpaceApp(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val arts = listOf(
        ...
    )

    var artState by remember {
        mutableStateOf(arts[0])
    }

    fun navigateToNextArt() {
        ...
    }

    fun navigateToPreviousArt() {
        ...
    }

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 24.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Art(imageResource = artState.drawableRes)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp))
        AboutArt(
            title = artState.title,
            author = artState.author,
            year = artState.year
        )
        NavigationArts(
            { navigateToNextArt() },
            { navigateToPreviousArt() }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Art(@DrawableRes imageResource: Int) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .border(width = 32.dp, color = Color.White)
            .shadow(elevation = 16.dp),
        ) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = imageResource),
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun AboutArt(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
        .background(color = colorResource(id = R.color.background_about_art)),
    title: String,
    author: String,
    year: Int,
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = title,
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.W300,
            )

            Row {
                Text(
                    text = author,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W800
                )

                Text(
                    text = " ($year)"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NavigationArts(
    navigateToNext: () -> Unit,
    navigateToPrevious: () -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Button(onClick = ... }) {
            Text(text = "Previous")
        }

        Button(onClick = ... }) {
            Text(text = "Next")
        }
    }
}



Проблема в том, что Art(...) - изображение занимает все пространство по вертикали, не оставляя место под AboutArt(...) - описание изображения и NavigationArts(...) - кнопки навигации между изображениями.

Скорее всего, Image занимает весь размер ибо никто ее не ограничивает. Выдайте картинке Modifier.weght(1f) чтобы она занимала только оставшееся от других элементов место и установите у нее contentScale чтобы она имела правило масштабирования.

Вернее не картинке, а Surface, ведь это она лежит в Column. И картинка подтянется...наверное. А еще лучше сделать  другой макет для ориентации - кнопки навигации по краям и высоту не забирать

@vitidev задать вес 'Modifier.weght(1f)' для контейнера с изображением и правда хороший совет, спасибо! Но он хорошо сработал только в альбомной ориентации, в портретной рамка вокруг картинки 'Modifier.border(width = 32.dp, color = Color.White)' получилась вытянутая по вертикали, т.к. теперь Surface занимает всю свободную область.

Размещение нужно такое
отступ
картинка
отступ
подпись
отступ до самого низа
навигация

И чтобы подпись была всегда видна, и чтобы картинка ужималась в размерах.Проблема в том, что картинка не знает сколько высоты ей можно взять. Column не лимитирует размер. Modifier.weight(1f) не помогает, ведь применяясь к Surface он растягивает его по всей высоте, а если применить к картинке, то навигация прижмется к подписи.
У вас слишком много вложенных блоков. Убираем лишнее
data class ArtState(
    @DrawableRes val drawableRes: Int,
    val title: String,
    val author: String,
    val year: Int
)

@Composable
fun Art(
    @DrawableRes imageResource: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .shadow(elevation = 16.dp)
            .border(width = 32.dp, color = Color.White)
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(32.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = imageResource),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Inside
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun NavigationArts(
    navigateToNext: () -> Unit,
    navigateToPrevious: () -> Unit,
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Button(onClick = navigateToNext) { Text(text = "Previous") }
        Button(onClick = navigateToPrevious) { Text(text = "Next") }
    }
}

@Composable
fun AboutArt(
    title: String,
    author: String,
    year: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(color = Color.Gray)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = title,
                fontSize = 24.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.W300,
            )

            Row {
                Text(
                    text = author,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W800
                )
                Text(text = " ($year)")
            }
        }
    }
}

Вот решение через слоты. Нет смысла комбинировать Spacer + padding, если можно задать просто padding. Также убрал лишнюю вложенность Column->Column
@Composable
fun ArtSpaceApp(artState: ArtState, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 24.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        MyLayout(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            content = {
                Art(
                    imageResource = artState.drawableRes,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        // убрал лишние Spacer
                        .padding(top = (32.dp + 20.dp), bottom = (16.dp + 24.dp))
                )
            },
            bottomContent = {
                AboutArt(
                    title = artState.title,
                    author = artState.author,
                    year = artState.year,
                )
            }
        )

        NavigationArts(
            { },
            { }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
    bottomContent: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    SubcomposeLayout(modifier = modifier) { constraints: Constraints ->
        // тут bottom определяет свой размер. По ширине пусть берет все, а по высоте не более ей нужного
        val bottomPlaceable: Placeable = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Bottom, bottomContent).map {
            it.measure(Constraints(maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth))
        }.first()

        // а тут основной контент определяет свой размер. Из общей высоты вычитаем bottom и пусть умещается
        // по высоте, а по ширине там сработает ContentScale
        val contentPlaceable: Placeable = subcompose(SlotsEnum.Main, content).map {
            it.measure(
                Constraints(
                    maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                    maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight - bottomPlaceable.height
                )
            )
        }.first()

        // размещаем
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            // центрируем
            contentPlaceable.placeRelative((constraints.maxWidth - contentPlaceable.width) / 2, 0)
            // приклеиваем bottom к картинке
            bottomPlaceable.placeRelative(0, contentPlaceable.height)
        }
    }
}

enum class SlotsEnum {
    Main,
    Bottom
}

Если нужно вывести мелкую картинку, то подпись может быть слишком высоко, поэтому в MyLayout можно передать минимальную высоту и сделать что-то типа
maxHeight = min(myminHeight, constraints.maxHeight - bottomPlaceable.height)

Попробую то же самое с ConstraintLayout. Если получится, то дополню ответ.

@Composable
fun ArtSpaceApp(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    ...
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 24.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Column(
            modifier = modifier,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Art(
                imageResource = artState.drawableRes,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = 32.dp, bottom = 16.dp)
                    .requiredHeightIn(min = 0.dp, max = 500.dp)
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(24.dp))
            AboutArt(
                title = artState.title,
                author = artState.author,
                year = artState.year,
            )
        }
        NavigationArts(
            { navigateToNextArt() },
            { navigateToPreviousArt() }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Art(
    @DrawableRes imageResource: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Surface(modifier = modifier.shadow(elevation = 16.dp)) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(width = 32.dp, color = Color.White)
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(32.dp),
                painter = painterResource(id = imageResource),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Inside
            )
        }
    }
}

Art(), Spacer() и AboutArt() обернул в отдельный контейнер Column, чтобы кнопки навигации были "прибиты" к нижней части экрана.
В самом Art() контейнер Surface пришлось обернуть в еще один контейнер, иначе не отображалась тень modifier.shadow(elevation = 16.dp).
На лучшую реализацию не претендую)

. 1 modifier, передаваемый в метод, нужно применять только к корневому блоку в этом методе. 2 Зачем вкладывать Surface в Surface можно просто продолжить цепочку modifier 3 Вариант с weight(1f) не будет работать если "Column в Column", то есть некому задать constraints чтобы картинка к ним прислушалась. 4 работает из за requiredHeightIn(...500) где вы задали constraints. Задайте 200 и она скукожится.

Ваша проблема в том, что картинка с радостью забирает всю доступную ей высоту, чтобы вписаться. Даже если вы обернете вложенный Column в BoxWithConstraints и используете его для задания размера этого Column, то это не сработает. Вам нужно задать ограничения картинке "область минус что там под ней". То есть вам это высчитать. Вы можете посчитать используя BoxWithConstraints  и onSizeChanged, но это лишняя композиция. Поэтому сразу идите в сторону SubcomposeLayout.

@vitidev [modifier, передаваемый в метод, нужно применять только к корневому блоку в этом методе] - я так понимаю это следует из правил композиции. Но как тогда правильно сделать так, чтобы передаваемый modifier был применен не только к корневому элементу, а и к дочерним элементам тоже?

fun AboutArt(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {     Surface(         modifier = modifier             .background(color = Color.Gray)             .padding(16.dp)     ) {         Column(             modifier = Modifier                 .fillMaxWidth()         ) {...}     } }
В таком случае modifier.background() применяется только к Surface, а вложенный в него Column так и остается без цвета.
Применять modifier.background() к каждым вложенным контейнерам не кажется хорошей идеей.

Это потому что Surface имеет свой параметр color, который и применяется к контенту и перезаписывает ваш цвет. Передаваемый modifier это больше к компоновке (чтобы лишний блок чисто для отступов не заводить), а не "всё на свете". Так что не стесняйтесь у вашего компонента заводить параметры color-ы, padding-и для управления контентом. Пример тот же surface или Lazy*Grid

Ну или выносите Surface наружу, чтобы компонент выражал сам "контент". Surface как бы для этого и придуман.

@vitidev Спасибо!
